# Retrieving Image From Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

The app run successfully , but the image did not show up in the table cell.

```
let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("restaurants/restaurantImage")
    dbRef.observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
        let downloadURL = snapshot.value as! String
        let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: downloadURL)
        storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
            let pic = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.picArray.append(pic!)

        }
        self.tableViewHongKong.reloadData()
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move `self.tableViewHongKong.reloadData()` inside your completion handler. With your current code you reload the table before the asynchronous function would finish.

You shouldn't do force unwrapping unless you are 100% sure that data will actually return and that the UIImage initializer will succeed.

```
let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("restaurants/restaurantImage")
    dbRef.observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
        let downloadURL = snapshot.value as! String
        let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: downloadURL)
        storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
            guard let imageData = data, let pic = UIImage(data: imageData) else { return }
            self.picArray.append(pic)
            self.tableViewHongKong.reloadData()
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The images do not appear because you are reloading your table view before any pictures are appended to the array. The `data(withMaxSize:` starts an asynchronous request that gets a response after you have reloaded the table view.

If you move `self.tableViewHongKong.reloadData()` inside the `data(withMaxSize:` response block, you will reload the table view after you append each successfully loaded image.

Answer (score 0):

Even if Callam already answered your question, I am still posting this since it is probably better way for doing it.

Instead of writing all that code just to display one image, you can use **Glide** which works very well with Firebase plus it is well documented in Firebase Docs. Check it out, it made everything a lot easier for me when I started using it.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui